Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis by Sheldon Axler Exercise 14 of Chapter 2A
I am studying Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis by Sheldon Axler & working on Exercise 14 of Chapter 2A
Here is the image:

The claim is that the sum of all 3 colored shapes, is 90.5, while simply taking the area of the larger triangle, yields 90.
For context: I am coming from undergrad analysis and taking a look at measure theory, probability theory, and abstract algebra.
I first read the chapter, pretty much skimming. Then I go back and read more thoroughly. I saw this skimming, and am still failing to realize how this is happening despite reading more thorough.
I cannot tell if the solution is right under my eyes geometrically, or if there is something less intuitive going on.
Thanks!

What larger triangle?  ((Hint))

The line from $(0,0)$ to $(20,9)$ does not go through the point $(11,5).$  It comes close.  i.e. the larger figure is not a triangle at all, and the line that appears to be the hypotenuse has a slight bend it it.  The small triangle formed by the three points listed has an area of surplus $\frac 12$

@user317176
I somewhat understand. Say where (11,5) is, is at (5,5). Specifically, where all shapes look like they intersect and share a point. We would have the same area, 90 as the supposed big triangle. But, the area would change to 12.5+37.5+30=80. Again, we have a different area but it is now much more off (by 10). I can now see visually after your comment, that if I were to grab that point and drag it along the x-axis, it would in fact appear like it was bended. I guess though, I don't understand how to apply this to measure theory. Seems like a continuity aspect I may not understand.

I don't see the relevance of this "problem"/ illustration to measure theory, either.  But, I haven't read this book.

This type of problem isn't usually directly applicable to the topic at hand.  Rather, the moral is "be aware of your assumptions".  Here, the larger quadrilateral has area $90.5$.  That the triangle formed by the points $(0,0), (20,0), (20,9)$ has area $90$ is also true, but we shouldn't expect them to be equal.

@BrianMoehring that makes sense and ultimately was what I had perceived from it.

DISCUSSION :
When we have a larger triangle cut by a line Parallel to Base , we must get a smaller similar triangle with same angles.
Largest triangle [ which is half the rectangle ] has Base angle $A=\tan^{-1}{(9/20)}$
Yellow triangle [ which is lower ] has Base angle $B=\tan^{-1}{(5/11)}$
That itself alerts us that we do not have a large triangle made of Red Blue & Yellow : It just looks like a large triangle.
Blue triangle [ which is upper ] has Base angle $C=\tan^{-1}{(4/9)}$
It confirms that we do not have a large triangle : It just looks like a large triangle.
Extra Details :
With the ratios given , the $\tan{(\cdot)}$ values can be compared , without taking inverses. I am just listing the actual values here to high-light the minor variations in angles :
$A=24.23$ : what over-all triangle should have
$B=24.44$ : largest
$C=23.96$ : smallest
Thus we see that Base angle is larger than what the over-all triangle should have , hence it is bulging outward.
Then the smallest angle makes it come back to reach the rectangle comer.
The bulge accounts for the Extra Area.
Hence , we do not have a large triangle , we just have a quadrilateral made of Red Blue & Yellow.
Alternatively , we can compute the 3 hypotenuses & use triangle area formula when given the 3 sides : It will work out to $0.5$ which is the Extra Area given by the outward bulge.
